# Node Express asynchronous db request: Display pending message?

Tags: node.js, express, callback, status, pending-transition

Is it somehow possible to display a status message while fetching a database request from some API with Node.js and Express.js? The db request is taking some minutes... I'd like to display a status message like "pending request.." in the browser as long as it takes to get the results.. is that possible in some way?
I know the request either is completed or failed, and I would probably need some state object or some kind of callback in the browser to do that, but I have no idea how..

Comment: Display pending message, start request, wait for response, display error or success message based on response. Have you tried anything? There is nothing conceptually difficult about this.

Comment: Could you add some basic examples of your code in the question? It's hard to tell what specific part you are confused about.